Error related to AlarmManager permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM or android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM
I have an related to AlarmManager:
receiver.BootCompletedReceiver.onReceive. Someone help me fix error, this occurs when user update app on Android 14? Thank u very much
Exception : java.lang.SecurityException Remote stack trace
  at com.android.server.alarm.AlarmManagerService$5.set (AlarmManagerService.java:3240)
  at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub.onTransact (IAlarmManager.java:262)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal (Binder.java:1405)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact (Binder.java:1341)
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Caller com.eup.faztaa needs to hold android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM or android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM to set exact alarms.
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3071)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:3055)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:3038)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2980)
  at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set (IAlarmManager.java:487)
  at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl (AlarmManager.java:1110)
  at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl (AlarmManager.java:1070)
  at android.app.AlarmManager.setExact (AlarmManager.java:834)
  at com.eup.faztaa.receiver.BootCompletedReceiver.onReceive
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4975)
Caused by android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
  at com.android.server.alarm.AlarmManagerService$5.set (AlarmManagerService.java:3240)
  at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub.onTransact (IAlarmManager.java:262)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal (Binder.java:1405)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact (Binder.java:1341)


Since you have not provided code segment related to this hard to pin point what is the issue. But here are general steps.
when updating android Android 13 (API level 33) to Android 14 (API level 34) there are 2 major API differences might give you above security exception.
1. Starting from Android 14, setting exact alarms requires the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission or android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM
1.1 Add the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission to your app's manifest file:

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />

1.2. Request the permission dynamically at runtime using

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ALARM_PERMISSION = 123;

    public void requestAlarmPermission() {
      String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM};
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_CODE_ALARM_PERMISSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
      super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ALARM_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          // Permission granted! Set your exact alarm here
          setExactAlarm();
        } else {
          // Handle permission denied scenario (e.g., inform user)
          Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }
    }

2.In Android 14 (API level 34), using mutable intents (specifically PendingIntent with FLAG_MUTABLE) is no longer recommended due to security concerns.
// If you are using any mutable pending intents, If you can change them to mutable intents of use alternative way to achieve functionality.

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);


Before I have a question: stackoverflow.com/questions/78562623/… Can you please take another look to assist me? However, my app is not an alarm app, it only has a feature to push notifications at scheduled times. The use of .permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM is prohibited on Google Play Store?
